# Usage of "brook" to mean "burp"?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, orthography

Has anyone ever come across ?*brook* (not too sure about spelling) used instead of *burp*?

> I brooked/I burped.
>
> Was that you brooking/burping?

It may be derived from Scottish Gaelic.

Answer (score 13):

Scots Gaelic does use *bruchd* for "burp". The word may have entered Scots dialectal English as "brook"; I've not come across it (but I'm not Scottish).

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yaMFAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=belch&f=false

[image: Patrick Macfarlane's English/Gaelic dictionary]

Answer (score 1):

The OED has *ruck*, *ruct* and but are obsolete and rare, with quotations from 16th to 17th century.

[*Nall's Glossary of East Anglian Dialect*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jnJH4vqF8rsC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=bruchd%20brook&source=bl&ots=p_i0P10hGX&sig=hJ_K4jheGBO7Psn8vJ-fBCN5M2M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r1rrT9nxHcvWsgbD9L2ZBg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bruchd%20brook&f=false) (1866) includes:

> **Broak, Brock.** To belch. Gael., ***bruchd***; Fris. and Dut., ***brake***.

This is interesting, it gives variants from Celtic and Germanic languages, although they could each be independently imitative of the sound and unrelated.

### English verb, *brook*

One of the OED definitions of the verb *brook* is:

> To make use of (food); in later usage, to digest, retain, or bear on the stomach.

It has quotations from *c*950, to 1598's:

> So fatte that men can hardlie brooke them.

Other definitions include being able to endure something (i.e. to stomach it), or to find something agreeable.

According to [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=brook&allowed_in_frame=0), the verb comes from:

> "to endure," O.E. *brucan* "use, enjoy, possess; eat; cohabit with," from P.Gmc. **bruk-* "to make use of, enjoy" (cf. O.S. *brukan*, O.Fris. *bruka*, O.H.G. *bruhhan*, Ger. *brauchen* "to use," Goth. *brukjan*), from PIE root **bhrug-* "to make use of, have enjoyment of" (cf. L. *fructus*). Sense of "use" applied to food led to "be able to digest," and by 16c. to "tolerate."

### English noun, *brook*

The noun *brook* means a small stream, but originally meant a torrent or strong flowing stream.

### Gaelic *bruchd*

[Dwelly's Classic Scottish Gaelic Dictionary](http://www.cairnwater.co.uk/gaelicdictionary/index.aspx?Language=en&txtSearch=bruchd) (first published 1901-1911) includes:

- *bruchd*:  Sudden rushing forth, as of a multitude, sally, any sudden burst or disruption. 2 Belch. 3 Heap, large quantity, glut. 4 Bulge. 5 Rift
- *brùchd-ruadhain*: Belching from an overloaded stomach.
- *rudhain*: Brùchd rudhain, *the acid return from the stomach*.

This is most likely the source of the term you heard.